# SQL Table primary key setting

Tags: sql, foreign-keys, primary-key, derby

I'm trying to make a program that has to manage some databases with derby.

In this program, I'm creating two tables, one called "customers" (that has one primary key that is the ID number of the person), and one called "transactions", in which I want one column to reference to the ID of the customer, which I would do through a Foreign key. However, this customer could perform several transactions, so that the actual key would be a combination of the date of the transaction and the id of the customer. Can this be made through the foreign key? Or am I very confused? I would really appreciate any help you guys could give me.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

It is best to also have a transaction ID. use that id column as the primary key in your transaction table, and have a foreign key user_id to relate to the user.id. Then you can uniquely identify each transaction, all transactions for a user, or query out other things like all transaction within a day for all users, for a set of users and so on.